# Google ADX Seller Rest API: get report by custom currency

Tags: google-api, adx

I'm using Google ADX API to get revenues report by date range.

By default I'm getting the revenues in ILS but I what to get the currency in USD or EUR and I don't want to use currency conversions like https://www.google.com/finance/converter

According to the formal documentation api (https://developers.google.com/ad-exchange/seller-rest/reference/v1.1/reports/generate) I didn't find any way for this issue..

Thats what i'm doing in my php code:

```
$params = array(
  'metric' => array('EARNINGS'),
  'dimension' => array('DATE', 'AD_TAG_NAME', 'AD_TAG_CODE','CUSTOM_CHANNEL_NAME', 'CUSTOM_CHANNEL_ID'),
  'sort' => '+DATE'
  //'currency' => 'usd' - try to add custom currency but unsuccess
);
$service = new Google_Service_AdExchangeSeller($client);
$service->accounts_reports->generate($accountId, $dateFrom, $dateTo, $params);
print_r($report['header']); //print: [currency] => ILS
```

Does anyone know how to do it?
Thanks

Comment: wild guess: it returns the currency that the account is set to.

Comment: Ok I solved it after talking with google ADX support that's what i added: 
$service = new Google_Service_AdExchangeSeller($client); $service>setDefer(true); $reportRequest = $service->accounts_reports->generate($accountId, $dateFrom, $dateTo, $params); 
$reportRequest = $reportRequest->setQueryParam('currency', "USD"); 
$report = $this->client->execute($reportRequest);